# HTML/JavaScript Form Muli List Select Alert not working

Tags: javascript, html, list, select, alert

I have the following form and javascript:

```js
function test() {
  var options = document.getElementById('genres1').options,
    count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].selected) count++;
  }

  alert(options);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="genres" id="genres1" size="6">
    <option value="r&b">R&B</option>
    <option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
    <option value="blues">Blues</option>
    <option value="newAge">New Age</option>
    <option value="classical">Classical</option>
    <option value="opera">Opera</option>
    </select><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="How many are selected?" onclick="test();" />
</form>
```

I'm trying to produce an alert message which will give the number of items selected by the user from the list.  I keep hitting dead ends, including not being able to select more than one option. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the number of items selected by the user is not showing is because you're not displaying the count.

you're doing `alert(options);` , I'd assume that was a mistake and you meant to write `alert(count);`.

secondly, for you to be able to select more than one option the solution below should do:

```
<form>   
   <select name="genres" id="genres1" size="6" multiple> <!-- note the use of "multiple" -->
      <option value="r&b">R&B</option>
      <option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
      <option value="blues">Blues</option>
      <option value="newAge">New Age</option>
      <option value="classical">Classical</option>
      <option value="opera">Opera</option>
   </select><br><br>
   <input type="button" value="How many are selected?" onclick="test();"/>
</form>
```

Also, keep in mind selecting multiple options vary in different operating systems and browsers:

- For windows: Hold down the control (ctrl) button to select multiple
  options
- For Mac: Hold down the command button to select multiple options

Comment: Thanks for the clear up it's now working perfectly! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please check this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function test()
{
  count = 0;
  var x=document.getElementById("genres1");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
     if(x.options[i].selected ==true){
          alert(x.options[i].value);
          count++;
      }
  }
  alert(count)
}
</script>
```

and html code

```
<form>   
<select name="genres" id="genres1" size="6"  multiple="">
<option value="r&b">R&B</option>
<option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
<option value="blues">Blues</option>
<option value="newAge">New Age</option>
<option value="classical">Classical</option>
<option value="opera">Opera</option>
 </select><br><br>
<input type="button" value="How many are selected?" onclick="test();"/>
</form>
```